# Next & previous links: Not showing a link if there isn't a next page

Tags: php, wordpress

I've followed the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links) (at the bottom) to create next and back buttons at the bottom of my page.

It seems to work fine until I get to the last page where the link just redirects me back to the first page. Is there a way to say if there isn't a next page to not show the link? I assumed thats what the if statement was supposed to do!!

```
<?php
$pagelist = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order&sort_order=asc');
$pages = array();
foreach ($pagelist as $page) {
   $pages[] += $page->ID;
}

$current = array_search(get_the_ID(), $pages);
$prevID = $pages[$current-1];
$nextID = $pages[$current+1];
?>                  

<?php if (!empty($prevID)) { ?>
    <a class="back" href="<?php echo get_permalink($prevID); ?>">BACK</a>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>
    <a class="next" href="<?php echo get_permalink($nextID); ?>">NEXT</a>
<?php } ?>
```

**p.s Please don't move my question to the Wordpress Stack - that seems to be dying a bit of a death and doesn't get many responses!**

---

My Pages are setup like this:

Parent page

- Sub page 1
- Sub page 2
- Sub page 3

I've created a link on the parent page to goto the first subpage. Then on the subpage template I've got the code above. I just want the next link to appear on each page then when it gets to page 3 it shouldn't show the next link.

Comment: This line `<?php if (!empty($nextID)) { ?>` Should do that for you, if you do `var_dump($nextID)` on the last page, what do you get?

Comment: @jakenoble It just says the words `int(248)` next to the link. That's the ID of the first page. This is the problem, it just links back to the first page on the last one.

Comment: What is in `var_dump($pages)`?

Comment: @jakenoble It's just dumped all the parent page id's in this format: `array(65) { [0]=> int(126) [1]=> int(135) [2]=> int(250) [3]` etc

Comment: after your edited question, you should get Child pages ids of the current page id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are saying that this is effectively looping around then $nextID must never be empty, which would be why the link was always displayed.

You could set a $firstID, ie

```
$firstID = pages[0];
```

and then check;

```
if ($firstID != $nextID ) {

   // Display link

}
```

Comment: It's still looping around to the first page.

Comment: @Rob, could you do a `var_dump($pages)` and put the full output array into your question? It'll help to resolve the problem

Comment: @deifwud It's in the comments on my question.

Comment: @Rob, need the full array ideally so we can see the first and last elements of the array

Comment: @McNab This code is on my subpages, it's now linking to the next parent page. I only want it to link to subpages and when it's at the end it shouldn't display a link.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I didn't realise that. I'll leave this answer up so everyone can see the comments and know not to come up with this again.

Comment: @McNab Actually it works out well, I'm going to keep it like this. All my pages are colour coded so they can literally work their way through the site (it's essentially a large document in a website form so is meant to be read from start to finish).